# Auto-login to internet script

Tags: scripting, wicd, autologin

For me to connect to internet I need to login first. Normally I do this manually (by opening my browser then at the first URL I enter I am redirected to the ISP's login page). However there is a Perl [script](http://pastebin.com/1V6zBkL8) that does this automatically (each time the PC is booted). How do I make use of this script? (Where and how do I tell Debian to use this script)

note: i use *[network-manager](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/network-manager)*.

Comment: Are you using NetworkManager, wicd, ifupdown (/etc/network/interfaces) or something else to connect?

Comment: @jofel: Why don't you make this an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need a post-connection script for wicd. You can set it in `/etc/wicd/wireless-settings.conf` or `/etc/wicd/wired-settings`. Another way is to use wicd-gtk: there is a "Scripts" button in the network's settings page.

Another way is to put the script into `/etc/wicd/scripts/postconnect/`. Then it should be run automatically after every connection to a network.

For more information, see [here](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/moinmoin/Adding%20pre%20and%20post%20%28dis%29connection%20scripts).

Comment: ok, i need a bit of help here, what i have done so far:
-my script is called firewall.pl and i copied it to `/etc/wicd/scripts/postconnect` and made it executable (by doing `chmod +x`).
-i opened the gui and entered the params: http://i.imgur.com/khIVx.png
-booted my pc, but no dice. apparently the script isn't being run by wicd for i still have to manually login.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @sterz My answer was not 100% complete, I'll edit it: Either put the script into `/etc/wicd/scripts/*/` or set it in the settings of the particular connection, where you need the *full path* to the script.  The arguments `wired` etc. are added to the command line by `wicd` automatically, so you do not need to specify them. Have you tried to call the script by hand?